# What is meant by sample estimates in this binom test in R?

Tags: r, statistics

What is meant by sample estimates in this binom test. They don't seem to change with change in `porbability of success`. I have tried to find it's meaning in documentation and on google but can't see it. I also tried to hand compute it, to check if it meant any thing but still I cannot see what it really means. **Any idea?**

> binom.test(60, 300, 0.3)

```
    Exact binomial test

data:  60 and 300
number of successes = 60, number of trials = 300, p-value = 0.0001137
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.3
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1562313 0.2498044
sample estimates:
probability of success 
               0.2
```

> binom.test(60, 300, 1/6)

```
    Exact binomial test

data:  60 and 300
number of successes = 60, number of trials = 300, p-value = 0.1216
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to     0.1666667
95 percent confidence interval:
0.1562313 0.2498044
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                0.2
```

> binom.test(60, 300, 0.5)

```
    Exact binomial test

data:  60 and 300
number of successes = 60, number of trials = 300, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1562313 0.2498044
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                 0.2
```

Comment: Where did you see the term 'sample estimates'? I don't see it in the help file. Anyway, by doing `?binom.test`, you will see that the function call, say `binom.test(60, 300, 0.3)` carries out a test of the null hypothesis `H_0: p = 0.3`. Under the null hypothesis, the probability distribution is `Binomial(300, 0.3)`, and the observed probability of success is `60/300 = 0.2`. So in all of the examples above, we have the same observed probability of success `60/300`. What is changing is the hypothesis. Let me know if this helps of if further clarification is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use your second chunk of code to explain (it is the same for all).

Imagine rolling a die. The probability of rolling a `6` if the die is fair is `1/6`. This is the third argument of the `binom.test` function. Therefore, in your example, the successes that you would expect would be `300 / 6 = 50`. This implies a (hypothesized) probability of success of `1/6`.

However, you observed `60` successes. These `60` observed successes are used to calculate the success sample estimate i.e. the value that you see at the bottom. This is calculated as `60 / 300 = 0.2`.

The binomial test then is used to test whether the proportion of 6s that you observed is significantly higher than would be expected by chance (i.e. 50 if the die is fair).